# -/+50 usecs jitter on hpet0 interrupt in Ubuntu kernel

Tags: kernel

I'm successfully running a realtime application on kernel 3.2 with RT_PREEMPT patch (not on Ubuntu, hardware is core i5). My app is cyclically driven by a hook that I added to hpet0.

Now I'm trying to run the realtime application on Ubuntu 16.04.1, using the same hardware. For that purpose I took kernel 4.4.0-21.37 and applied RT_PREEMPT patch-4.4.39-rt50.

Ubuntu boots up properly.

The problem is that I get a -/+50 usecs jitter on the hpet0 interrupt, or more accurately, the time in which the hook function is executed.

I had the same results with Ubuntu 13.04 and kernel 3.8.8...

Is there anything in the Ubuntu kernel patches that might cause such jitter?
Any specific method to eliminate the jitter on hpet0?

Thanks a lot,

Nir.